# HTML5 Canvas in layers, and centered?

Tags: html, css, canvas

How would I go about using *HTML5*'s *canvas* to make mulitple *canvas layers* ontop of each other, while being centered properly on the page (via *CSS3*)? I seem to be having issues getting both steps to properly work out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is having all of your `canvas` tags contained within a single `div` like such:

```
<div id="canvasHold">
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS to center:

```
#canvasHold {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: -400px; /* Negative half of the width */
    margin-top: -300px; /* Negative half of the height */
}

#canvasHold canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Of course, setting the height of a canvas element in CSS is **not** the same as setting the height and width as HTML attributes of each canvas tag.  It wouldn't hurt to set them to `100%` in CSS, but you should definitely set them as HTML attributes.

Comment: this decade-old solution works for me but I wonder if there's a better approach nowadays?